# New DataFrame boolean column that checks whether or not any of certain columns equal 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `pd.DataFrame` and list of columns:

```
col_list = ["med_a", "med_c"]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'med_a': [0, 0, 1, 0], 'med_b': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'med_c': [0, 1, 1, 0]})

print(df)
>>>
    med_a   med_b   med_c
0   0       0       0
1   0       0       1
2   1       1       1
3   0       1       0
```

I want to make a new column (`new_col`) that holds either True/False (or 0/1) if any of the columns in `col_list` is equal to 1, for each row. So the result should become:

```
     med_a  med_b   med_c   new_col
0   0       0       0       0
1   0       0       1       1
2   1       1       1       1
3   0       1       0       0
```

I know how to select only those rows where at least one of the columns in is equal to 1, but that doesn't check only those columns in `col_list`, and it doesn't create a new column:

```
df[(df== 1).any(axis=1)]

print(df)
>>>
    med_a   med_b   med_c
1   0       0       1
2   1       1       1
3   0       1       1
```

How would I achieve the desired result? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're so close! Just filter the df with the `col_list` before [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html#pandas-dataframe-any) on axis=1 + [`astype(int)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas-series-astype).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

col_list = ["med_a", "med_c"]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'med_a': [0, 0, 1, 0],
                             'med_b': [0, 0, 1, 1],
                             'med_c': [0, 1, 1, 0]})


df['new_col'] = df[col_list].any(axis=1).astype(int)

print(df)
```

---

Or via [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df[col_list].any(axis=1), 1, 0)
```

---

```
   med_a  med_b  med_c  new_col
0      0      0      0        0
1      0      0      1        1
2      1      1      1        1
3      0      1      0        0
```

---

Timing information via perfplot:

[image: perfplot of np.where vs asint]

`np.where` is faster than `astype(int)` up to 100,000 rows at which point they are about the same.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

np.random.seed(5)
col_list = ["med_a", "med_c"]


def gen_data(n):
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'med_a': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=n),
                                   'med_b': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=n),
                                   'med_c': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=n)})


def np_where(df):
    df['new_col'] = np.where(df[col_list].any(axis=1), 1, 0)
    return df


def astype_int(df):
    df['new_col'] = df[col_list].any(axis=1).astype(int)
    return df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    out = perfplot.bench(
        setup=gen_data,
        kernels=[
            np_where,
            astype_int
        ],
        labels=[
            'np_where',
            'astype_int'
        ],
        n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(25)],
        equality_check=None
    )
    out.save('perfplot_results.png', transparent=False)
```

Comment: Ah, I had a feeling I was close... Thanks! Will accept this answer in 10 minutes (when SO allows me to do so).

Comment: I don’t think so that `np.where` is a good option here. As you’re already checking with `axis=1` am I missing anything? BTW you’re fast, and the 1st option looks perfect for the task.

Comment: @Nk03 I believe `np.where` is faster converting converting a boolean index of `True` and `False` to ones and zeros than `astype(int)` is. I'll run some benchmarking and add it to my question when it completes.

Comment: Lol. In my machine `as_type(int)` is faster for large dataframe. I guess as_type(int) is also a vectorized operation.